# Google Sheets - Replacing specific parts of formulas in an array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script to replace the references of some formulas with their current value, before copy to a new range.

I'd like to keep the rest of the formula so I can store a history of values without using new sheets.

I tried this code, but no changes occurred in the formulas:

```
function repformulas() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var formrange = sheet.getRange("h1:h6");
var formulas = formrange.getFormulas();
var reprange = sheet.getRange("c2:c6");
var pasterange = sheet.getRange("i1:i6");
var regexp = /(.{2})\s./g;
  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++) {
         formulas[i][j] = formulas[i][j].replace(regexp, repvalue[i][j]);
    }
  }
sheet.insertColumns(9, 1);
pasterange.setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

I have this in the formulas array:

```
["=eomonth(I1;1)"] ["=($C$2/3869,01-1)*100"] ["=($C$3/4625,68-1)*100"] ["=($C$4/8494.69-1)*100"] ["=($C$5/15056.32-1)*100"] ["=($C$6/23540,01-1)*100"]
```

And I want to replace it with this:

```
["=eomonth(I1; 1)"] ["=(4001.02/3869.01-1)*100"] ["=(4805.08/4625.68-1)*100"] ["=(8399.84/8494.69-1)*100"] ["=(15057.98/15056.32-1)*100"] ["=(23554.56/23540.01-1)*100"]
```

I will be very grateful if anyone can help me.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? In your sample input and output arrays, it seems that although the formula is retrieved from the cells `h1:h9`, the values of each `H6` of `["=H6-H10"] ["=H6/H12*100"] ["=H6/H13*100"]` are the different. I cannot understand about this situation. If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. So in order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. The input range should be `H1:H6` and the output `I1:I6`. I'll edit it.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. Can I ask you about your current question? 1. What is `,` of `3869,01-1`, `4625,68-1` and `23540,01-1` in `formulas array`. 2. You don't want to convert `I1` of `=eomonth(I1;1)`. Is my understanding correct? In this case, when the converted formulas are put to `I1:I6', I think that an error of `#REF!` occurs. How about this?

Comment: 1. Decimals are separated by comma in my country. 2. Yes. It's a problem that I have to solve. Before a new column is inserted,  `I1` value is `ago/19` (date formatted) , so `H1` is `sep/19`. A monthly trigger will be set to run this custom function. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying comments and updated question, I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put the formulas by converting a1Notations to the values.
- `I1` of `=eomonth(I1;1)` is the date object. You want to keep this and converted the other a1Notations.
- From your replying, it is `Decimals are separated by comma in my country.`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? The flow of this modification is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve formulas and values from the cells of `H1:H6` and `C1:H6`, respectively.
2. Retrieve the values of `C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, H1`.
3. Convert the retrieved formulas.

   - `,` is modified to `.`.
   - The a1Notations of `$C$2`, `$C$3`, `$C$4`, `$C$5` and `$C$6` are modified to the values from "C2" to "C6".
   - In this case, `=eomonth(I1;1)` is converted to the current value. So this value can be saved. When `sheet.insertColumns(9, 1)` is run, `I1` of `=eomonth(I1;1)` is updated to `J1`. I thought that this can be used.
4. Insert a column to the column "I".
5. Put the converted formulas to the cells of `I1:I6` which was inserted.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

```
function repformulas() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var formrange = sheet.getRange("h1:h6");
  var formulas = formrange.getFormulas();

  // --- I modified below script
  var [[_, _, _, _, _, H1], [C2], [C3], [C4], [C5], [C6]] = sheet.getRange("C1:H6").getValues();
  var obj = {C2: C2, C3: C3, C4: C4, C5: C5, C6: C6};
  var converted = formulas.map(function(e, i) {
    return i == 0 ? [H1] : [e[0].replace(/,/g, ".").replace(/\$[A-Z]\$\d+/, function(m) {return obj[m.replace(/\$/g, "")]})];
  });
  // ---

  var pasterange = sheet.getRange("i1:i6");
  sheet.insertColumns(9, 1);
  pasterange.setFormulas(converted);
}
```

#### References:

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, @Tanaike!!! At my localzone google sheet doesn't use period to separate decimals, so I changed the following line of the code: `return i == 0 ? [sheet.getRange("I1").getFormula()] : [e[0].replace(/\$[A-Z]\$\d+/, function(m) {return obj[m.replace(/\$/g, "")]}).replace(/\./g, ",")];`. Otherwise I'd get #ERROR.

Comment: @2badatcoding Thank you for replying and adding the information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.